# corners of a rectangular bended sheet in 3d

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, 3d, bezier-curve

I write a mesher for special geometric forms to train Computer Aided Engineering with them.

I need to display a **rectangular with rounded corners** in 3d.
It is a Stadium Shape/Obolong/Capsule Shape, like it named in this [post](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/117005/what-is-this-shape-that-looks-like-a-rectangle-with-rounded-ends-called).

The [2D form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ShyrO.png) is no problem.  [image: example]
But now I want to bend it around the y - axis. The extrema is a closed pipe, but what I want is more like a [parabolic cylinder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parabolic_cylinder_function), like a taco shell or a [Scutum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scutum).

The outer boundary is clear, it is like:
$$
x_i = x_a + sin(\alpha)*r_c \\
y_i = y_a + i*l_c \\
z_i = z_a + cos(\alpha)*r_c \\
$$
with

$$
-\frac{\Pi}{2} < \alpha < \frac{\Pi}{2} \\
l_c = length\ of\ sheet\\
r_c = width\ of\ sheet
$$

But now there are the corners. I don't know how to gave it a parametric shape and what where the name of these [lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AivJv.png), is it a spline, a bspline or a bezierspline or something other?

In CAD-Tools you could use a fillet for rounding the corners or bend the 2d form afterwards, like in this example:
[image: example]
But I don't know how to calculate the rounded corners.

Please help me.
Thank you

Comment: Who is the (anonymous !) downvoter who downvotes well written questions like this one ?